# Outlook reply, "No" to "Automatic Picture Download", results in attachments in reply email

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-redemption

My application dispatches HTML email notifications that have a couple of images.  We capture the reply message with a custom ribbon button.  When the user replies they are prompted to download content from the internet by a dialog.  If they select "No", when I get the item in VSTO it has three or four .jpg attachments.  If they select "Yes" I get no attachments, as expected.

The attachments are named "~WRDxxx.jpg" xxx most often being "000" but occasionally other numbers, and then image001.jpg, image002.jpg and so on.  The files exist and consume storage, under 1k (except for ~WRD... which is about 3.5k), but don't seem to contain any graphics.  I assume these are the pixels embedded by our email provider, and the largest is probably our logo although the accompanying file is empty.

We're using a mix of VSTO and Outlook Redemption to access the emails.

This problem affects 2007-2013, but the switch to off-by-default for inline makes the issue more pressing.

MIME message:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============4154024679712410635=="
MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: New Channel
From: Alfa Apricot <notifications@app.titanfile.com>
To: "Mark Blarg" <mark@blarg.onmicrosoft.com>
Date: Tue, 26 Aug 2014 18:54:37 -0000
Message-ID: <20140826185437.32642.87638@ds1.titanfile.com>
Reply-To: Message email reply
    <notifications+c1b349a6-ac4f-44a0-a3eb-ab647162a7a1@app.titanfile.com>

--===============4154024679712410635==
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="===============5446532731331882741=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--===============5446532731331882741==
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

string
--===============5446532731331882741==
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>TitanFile</title>
        <!--[if gte mso 6]>
        <style>
            table.mcnFollowContent {width:100% !important;}
            table.mcnShareContent {width:100% !important;}
        </style>
        <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Clipped to fit on SO  */
    </style></head>
    <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #fafafa;">
        <center>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #fafafa;height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;margin: 0;padding: 20px;border-top: 0;height: 100% !important;width: 100% !important;">
                        <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                    <!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templatePreheader" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;background-color: #ffffff;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="preheaderContent" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-right: 18px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-left: 18px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #808080;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 10px;line-height: 150%;text-align: left;">
                                            </td>
                                            <!--
 -->
                                            <td valign="top" width="180" class="preheaderContent" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-right: 18px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-left: 0;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #808080;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 10px;line-height: 150%;text-align: left;">
                                            </td>
                                            <!--
 -->
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // END PREHEADER -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                    <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateHeader" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;background-color: #ffffff;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="headerContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnImageBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
    <tbody class="mcnImageBlockOuter">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="padding: 9px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" class="mcnImageBlockInner">
                    <table align="left" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnImageContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td class="mcnImageContent" valign="top" style="padding-right: 9px;padding-left: 9px;padding-top: 0;padding-bottom: 0;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">




<a href="https://app.titanfile.com/channels/sGiKAv/wcgaIN/">

                                        <img align="right" alt="TitanFile Logo" src="cid:logo" style="max-width: 150px;padding-bottom: 0;display: inline !important;vertical-align: bottom;border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;" class="mcnImage">

</a>



                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnCaptionBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
    <tbody class="mcnCaptionBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td class="mcnCaptionBlockInner" valign="top" style="padding: 9px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">




<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionRightContentOuter" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td valign="top" class="mcnCaptionRightContentInner" style="padding: 0 9px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mcnCaptionRightImageContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td class="mcnCaptionRightImageContent" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">



<a href="https://app.titanfile.com/channels/sGiKAv/wcgaIN/">
    <img src="cid:avatar" height="48" width="48" style="border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none !important;vertical-align: bottom;" class="mcnImage">
</a>






                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <table class="mcnCaptionRightTextContentContainer" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                <tbody><tr>
                        <td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="color: #AAAAAA;text-align: left;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;">


<h1 style="display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 20px;font-style:
    normal;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: normal;margin: 0
    30px;text-align: left;color: #202020 !important;">
    Alfa Apricot</h1>

<h2 style="display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;font-style:
    normal;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: normal;margin:
    13px 30px;text-align: left;color: #404040 !important;">
     sent you a message 
</h2>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>




            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // END HEADER -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                    <!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateBody" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;background-color: #ffffff;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="bodyContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnTextBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
    <tbody class="mcnTextBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" class="mcnTextBlockInner" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">


                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="mcnTextContentContainer" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                    <tbody><tr>

                        <td valign="top" class="mcnTextContent" style="padding-top: 0px;padding-right: 18px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 18px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #505050;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;text-align: left;">


<div style="display: block !important;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;line-height: 100% !important;letter-spacing: normal;margin: 0 !important;text-align: left;color: #606060 !important; background: #f4f4f4; padding: 10px !important; height: 100% !important;">




        <blockquote style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;font-size:11pt;
            line-height: 18pt; font-family: Arial; color:#333333;font-weight:
            normal; padding: 10px 0;">
            Testing one for Dmitry
        </blockquote>



<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="mcnButtonBlock" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
    <tbody class="mcnButtonBlockOuter">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top: 0;padding-right: 18px;padding-bottom: 18px;padding-left: 18px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top" align="center" class="mcnButtonBlockInner">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="" class="mcnButtonContentContainer" style="border-top-left-radius: 5px;border-top-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;background-color: #26A026;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" valign="middle" class="mcnButtonContent" style="color: #FFFFFF;font-family: Arial;font-size: 16px;padding: 15px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                <a class="mcnButton " title="" href="https://app.titanfile.com/channels/sGiKAv/wcgaIN/" target="_self" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: -0.5px;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none !important;color: #FFFFFF !important;font-family: Arial;font-size: 16px;padding: 15px;word-wrap: break-word !important;">Reply to Message</a>


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>




</div>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>


            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>


</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // END BODY -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;">
                                    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateFooter" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-top: 0;border-bottom: 0;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="footerContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #808080;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 12px;line-height: 150%;padding-top: 18px;padding-right: 18px;padding-bottom: 18px;padding-left: 18px;text-align: left;">
                                        <p>Reply to this email to post a message.</p>





                                                &copy; 2014 <a href="https://titanfile.com" title="TitanFile Inc.">TitanFile Inc.</a> 410 Conestogo Road, Suite 101 Waterloo, ON, N2L 4E2, Canada<br>




<p><a href="https://app.titanfile.com/options/notifications/">Don't want to see these notifications?</a></p>



</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="footerContent" style="padding-top: 18px;padding-bottom: 40px;border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #808080;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 10px;line-height: 150%;padding-right: 18px;padding-left: 18px;text-align: left;">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // END FOOTER -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- // END TEMPLATE -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>

--===============5446532731331882741==--
--===============4154024679712410635==
Content-Type: image/png
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <logo>

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGkAAAAWCAYAAADD9rIuAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJ
--===============4154024679712410635==
Content-Type: image/png
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <avatar>

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAAUZUlEQVR4nG2a2a+l13Hdf7WHbzjn
--===============4154024679712410635==--
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: So the question is "why does this happen and how do I stop it?"?

Comment: Have you tried to embed the files as attachments and refer to them in HTML by the content id (`<img src="cid:xyz`)?

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, that is the question

DmitryStreblechenko I have not, but I will right now and let you know - you have a habit of steering me right.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Tried the inline content approach, which took a bit of effort, but gave similar results.  Now the files I embedded have content, but the email and behaviour is otherwise identical.

Comment: Please show your MIME message. Outlook will never prompt to download images added as a attachments.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I can't eliminate all non-embedded images due to Mandrill pixels.  Standby for email, will edit question.

Comment: I had to clip the styles and much of the base64 content to make it fit. This might not be suitable data as Mandrill makes at least some changes to the content to add tracking pixels.